# How do I cross-reference objects by page number in R Markdown to Microsoft Word?

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown, documentation, bookdown, cross-reference

I am wondering how to cross-reference by page number, similar to the way that you can cross-reference section numbers (https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/cross-references.html) when generating Word documents from .Rmd files.

I am looking for something like the pageref command from LaTeX ([https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing#Introduction])[1](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing#Introduction), but for R Markdown to Word.

Comment: For certain documents, this would also be very nice to have for LaTex/PDF output.